# How can I access to some model in Backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a collection of models:

```
city = new M.City
App.citiesList = new C.CitiesList model: city
App.citiesList.fetch()
```

How can I access to the model with `id=15` for example?

I need something like `App.citiesList.find(15).name()`, *where `name()` is model function*

When I try to add function find to the collection it is incorrect.
When I try to iterate over `App.citiesList.models` - I see only one model or what it is.. I actually don't know.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `App.citiesList` is a Backbone collection then you'd want to use [`get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get):

> **get** collection.get(id)
>   Get a model from a collection, specified by **id**.

So this would get you your model from the collection:

```
fifteen = App.citiesList.get 15
```

And if you wanted to call a method on it:

```
App.citiesList.get(15).name()
```

You'd probably want to make sure you got something back from `App.citiesList.get 15` first though (unless you knew it was there of course). Since you're working in CoffeeScript you could use the [existence operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) like this:

```
name = App.citiesList.get(15)?.name()
#----------------------------^
```

to get 15's name or `undefined` in the `name` variable.

The `find` method on `App.citiesList` would be Underscore's [`find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) and that doesn't find an object with a particular ID.